# Mille Bornes Fast Play Rules Clarification

Tags: mille-bornes

[The Dujardin version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07679652D) has Fast Play Rules (see page 7 in the [manual](https://images-cdn.asmodee.us/filer_public/31/fc/31fc285a-2300-4d90-a55f-4c0415453e14/mib01_rules.pdf)). One of the rules allows players to immediately play a Remedy card right after receiving a Hazard card, and then immediately draw a new card, and then the game play will *resume according to the normal flow of play*. However, unlike the "Coup Fourré" move, the player does not gain or lose points.

I'm confused by what "resuming the normal flow of play" means in this context, especially compared to the Coup Fourré situation.

Let's say we have 4 players: North, East, South, and West, and the order of play is clockwise (N-E-S-W-N-E-S-W-...). North puts down a Hazard card onto South.

In the "Coup Fourré" move (page 12 in the [manual](https://images-cdn.asmodee.us/filer_public/31/fc/31fc285a-2300-4d90-a55f-4c0415453e14/mib01_rules.pdf)), if South has a Safety card, then South can immediately put that card down to remove the Hazard card, draw a replacement for the Safety card, and then South gets a move by drawing another card and then play/discard another card. After that, it's West's turn. East doesn't get any turn. Therefore, effectively, South hijacks the turn, interrupting the normal flow.

Under the Fast Play Rules, South is allowed to play a corresponding Remedy card immediately after North plays a Hazard card against South. Then South draws a replacement card for that Remedy card. So far this is simliar to the Coup Fourré move. Now, who's playing right after South draws that replacement? Is it West, just like in the Coup Fourré move? Or is it East, because it was North who put down the Hazard card, and East was supposed to play next (hence "resuming to the normal flow of play")?

The Fast Play Rules are not in the classic version but I still wonder which makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the "resume in normal order" text is there to emphasize the difference between this and the normal Coup Fourré move -- that is, that in your example, after South draws their replacement card, and North's turn ends, East takes the next turn as normal.

Answer (score 1):

It would be East's turn. You are right in assuming the normal flow of play moves to the next player in proper turn order, these rule adjustments allow you to remedy a hazard outside normal turn order when it's played, but it doesn't actually change the turn order, unlike Coup Fourré.